# tryton Gtk-ERROR Can't create a GtkStyleContext without a display connection

Tags: python, linux, centos, tryton

I have a problem with GTK whenever when I run the command `tryton` or `gnuhealth-client`, I receive error messages with a GTK problem:

```
$tryton
```

> (tryton:1754): Gtk-ERROR **: 12:53:39.748: Can't create a GtkStyleContext without a display connection
> Trappe pour point d'arrêt et de trace
> what can i do please ?

```
$ gnuhealth-client
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/gnuhealth/.local/bin/gnuhealth-client", line 34, in 
> from tryton.client import main
> File "/home/gnuhealth/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tryton/client.py",
> line 12, in 
> from tryton import gui
> File "/home/gnuhealth/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tryton/gui/**init**.py",
> line 3, in 
> from .main import *
> File "/home/gnuhealth/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tryton/gui/main.py",
> line 33, in 
> from tryton.gui.window.activity import Activity
> File "/home/gnuhealth/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tryton/gui/window/activity.py",
> line 23, in 
> class Activity():
> File "/home/gnuhealth/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tryton/gui/window/activity.py",
> line 25, in Activity
> activity_window = Gtk.Window()
> File "/home/gnuhealth/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gi/overrides/Gtk.py",
> line 521, in **init**
> "Gtk couldn't be initialized. "
> RuntimeError: Gtk couldn't be initialized. Use Gtk.init_check() if you want to handle this case.

Answer (score 0):

The desktop client must be run under an graphical session (X or Wayland for example).

Comment: i installed wayland :$sudo yum install epel-release $sudo yum install snapd $
sudo systemctl enable --now snapd.socket
Copy  $sudo ln -s /var/lib/snapd/snap /snap $
sudo snap install wayland --beta
now wayland is installed but nothing changed when i type $ tryton same error msg

Comment: But are you under a graphical session when starting the client? The client is a graphical application based on GTK+.

Comment: but if you have a ssh login using the "-X" or "-Y" switch, shouldn't you be able to export the application to your local display?  Or has that been broken in the later GTK libraries?